# MariaDB 10.3 won't restart after upgrade from 10.2 on RHEL 7

Tags: mariadb, rhel7

Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong after an upgrade from MariaDB10.2 to 10.3

```
[db@hawk ~]systemctl status mariadb.service
? mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.36 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           +-migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-09-10 07:06:55 +03; 16s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 3426 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3379 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3377 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3426 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: 2022-09-10  7:06:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: 2022-09-10  7:06:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: 2022-09-10  7:06:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: 2022-09-10  7:06:55 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: 2022-09-10  7:06:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk mysqld[3426]: Warning: Memory not freed: 520
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.36 database server.
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 10 07:06:55 hawk systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

Comment: Show the full log of `mariadb.service`.

Comment: I rebooted the server and it sorted itself. Not sure how. Afterwards ran mysql_upgrade --password and was able to get it successfully updated.